# Debian Unstable x64: ALSA equalizer plugin unavailable to i386 applications, no sound

Tags: audio, debian, alsa

I'm running Debian Unstable x64, but sometime use legacy applications or games that are only available in i386. With plain ALSA (there's only so much PulseAudio a sane person can take), i386 applications aren't getting any sound due to plugin problems.

I have the equalizer plugin for ALSA x64 installed and specified in my `.asoundrc` like so:

```
ctl.equal {
  type equal;
}
pcm.plugequal {
  type equal;
  slave.pcm "plug:dmix";
}
pcm.!default {
  type plug;
  slave.pcm plugequal;
}
```

This means that the i386 applications attempt to load the plugin as well, fail, and don't give me any sound at all - looks like this:

`ALSA lib dlmisc.c:254:(snd1_dlobj_cache_get) Cannot open shared library /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_pcm_equal.so`

Installing the plugin for both architectures seems impossible at face value: They conflict in `apt` and use the same file in the home directory to store their settings (I think? `.alsaequal.bin`), which they require to be in different formats. (Replacing one version with another without moving the file results in the error ".alsaequal.bin is the wrong length".)

Going through all the steps to change out the plugin and config file every time I use different architectures is a hassle and prone to errors, so I'd like to somehow be able to avoid it. Two options come to mind:

- Tell ALSA to use different rcfiles for i386 and x64
- Explicitly specify the path to .alsaequal.bin, which might allow me to run the plugin for both architectures. (It's configurable in .asoundrc but that just leads to option 1.)

I don't know how to do either, unfortunately. The latter would of course be preferred, but since it's not all that frequent and I use the equalizer mainly for music and movies, it would be alright if i386 applications would just use sound directly.

Thanks in advance!